# Блокировка изменения переменной JS

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как заблокировать изменение переменной в JS? может как-то отменять её изменение.

```
Ajax('POST', '/Controller/path', {}, function (result) {
        window.test = result.test;
        //как заблокировать изменение этой переменной. Ведь её можно изменить через консоль.
    });
```

Comment: А она где? глобальная? в функции? в методе? в модуле? в компоненте?

Comment: еще важно что именно за переменная

Comment: уточните пожалуйста вопрос. Вы хотите заблокировать значение переменной в javascript или вы хотите заблокировать значение того или иного атрибута html?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в глобальном объекте.

Comment: @ElvinNoMatter переменная js

Comment: @Tsyklop, покажи пример кода о чем ты говоришь, и как ты хотел менять эту _переменную_

Comment: @Grundy в том и прикол что я хочу запретит менять эту переменную после того как я зада ей значение. в шапку кинул.

Comment: @Tsyklop, что ты имеешь ввиду под запретить менять? что больше нельзя сделать `window.test = other`? или что нельзя сделать: `window.test.prop = 'prop'`? или все вместе? Захочешь ли ты сам когда-нибудь обновлять эту переменную?

Comment: В общем виде задача нерешаема, потому что благодаря консоли можно сохранить исходный объект _result.test_ и менять уже его

Comment: Если очень нужна подобная функциональность, то можно заменить переменную на объект с закрытой переменной + сеттер/геттер. Менее удобно, лишняя писанина, но работать будет как задумано.

Answer (score 1):

Такое можно сделать если объявить переменную с помощью Object.defineProperty.

Пример:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "test", {
   value: "Неизменяемое",
   writable: false, // запретить присвоение "test="
   configurable: false // запретить удаление "delete test"
});
```

Важно! Без use strict операция записи «молча» не сработает. Если установлен режим use strict, то дополнительно сгенерируется ошибка.

Comment: вот только это не поможет, если в отладчике сохранить значение, которое присваивается этому свойству. Его все так же можно будет менять как угодно

Answer (score 0):

Ну в актуальном стандарте такой возможности нет. Есть некоторые договоренности, например, если название переменной начинается с `_` то изменять ее значение напрямую не следует.

```
_superConst = "super"; //менять можно, но делая это вам будет стыдно
```

Но, я надеюсь, в ближайшем будущем в новом стандарте js будет доступно объявление переменной как `const`. Значение переменной, объявленной как `const` изменять физически запрещено.

```
const _superConst = "super"; //менять не получится
```

Использовать эту возможность сейчас можно, если вы подключите babel или любой другой js транслятор кода, способный превращать es6 в es5 javaScript.

Answer (score -4):

скажем у вас есть объект с наименованием `Person` и вы хотите создать для него статическое значение.

```
function Person(){
    this.name = "Peter";
}
```

затем создаете переменную и приравниваете инстансу этого объекта

```
var p1 = new Person();
```

[исходник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307243/how-to-declare-a-static-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: Это ответ не на тот вопрос.